# Php Header linking to different links depending on page

Tags: php, header

I recently changed my bilingual website of 23 html pages to 23 php pages (The site is: www.creativemindspcs.org.) With this change, I included php headers, footers, and navigation.

I cannot figure out how to change the header links based on what page I am on.

Example. The About Us page in English. In the header, I have a link that says "Espanol". When you click on that link, it should take you to the About Us Spanish page but now since the php header is included on all of the pages, it only links to one page and not the correct one.

How do I change those links depending on what page it needs to go to? Anyone have a good tutorial?

**HTML Code:**

```
<header><insert php code here> include('includes/header.php');
```

**Includes Header Code:**

```
<!--==============================header=================================-->

<div id="header" class="editable">

    <div class="inner" >

        <div class="meta-info">

        <div class="extra-wrap">

        <ul class="social-links">

        <li><a href="index.html">English</a></li>

        <li><a href="esp-index.html">Espa&#xF1;ol</a></li>

        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>



        <form id="main-search" action="search.php"  >

        <input type="text" name="search"  style="background-color:#CCCCCC" >

        <a class="search-submit" onClick="document.getElementById('main-search').submit()" ></a>
        </form>
        </div>


        <br><br><br><a href="supportus.html" class="button3">Donate</a>  <a href="apply.html" class="button4">Apply</a>     </div>

        <img src="site/images/CMLOGO.GIF" align="top" alt="Guitar Logo"><a href="index.html"></a>     

</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

        </div>
```

Comment: What do the actual URLs look like? Is the language code in them?

Comment: All the links say: <li><a href="esp-index.html">Espa&#xF1;ol</a></li> but since the header is included on every page, I don't know how to make the links go to different places depending on what current page they are on.

Comment: @Mike is going in a right direction, in php just give a language code in URL like ?lang=en and get the value by $_GET['lang'] create a switch or if statement to change to header however you want

Answer (score 1):

So the approach to bilingual pages is normally to store a hash of the different pieces of the site in different languages and then serve up the same template page. But in your case it looks like you have gone in a different but similar direction utilizing links. I'd say take a look here for starters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228018/php-multilingual-site

Comment: Thank you for the references. I will have to go educate myself. I'm in WAY over my head. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP **$_SERVER['variable_name']**

Check the array variables here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

I would probably use **$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']**, **$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']** or **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**.

You can see the possible results adding this on your included header to check the variable:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
echo "</pre>";
```

So, your link could be something like:

```
<a href="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>spanish.html">
```

Comment: Ok. I still don't get it. If I add the <a href="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; <?spanish.html"> to the header page, it'll only bring up the spanish.html page but I want it to change based on 23 different pages....

Comment: Using $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] you can check what's the actual page name and do some string split to get only the part you want…


Example:
$pathSplited =  split ("/", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$page = split ("-", $pathSplited[2]); // depend on your URL
<a href="esp-<?php $page[1]; ?>.html">

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache, I would suggest using `mod_rewrite` to rewrite your URLs. So for example, when the user accesses the page `esp-content.html` the URL will be rewritten to `content.html?lang=esp`. Then just include the language code in all your links:

```
$lang = (isset($_GET['lang'])) ? urlencode($_GET['lang']) . '-' : null;
echo '<a href="'.$lang.'content.html">';
```